# Is there a way to change state of workitem with java sdk for TFS?

Tags: java, tfs

I'm at a point where I cannot figure out how to change the state of a bug from "New" to anything I'v tried "Approved,Done,Closed" every time I get the following exception shown below. I have looked all over the internet and have found that the System.State field is a bit different than other fields. I thought okay well maybe there is a method to move the transition state but couldn't find that. I also saw a few posts in the .NET api where switching the state caused other fields in particular the reason field to become invalid. I don't think this is the issue though because as soon as I try to call field.setValue("Closed") it throws the exception.I looked with power tools and the System.State does show to be editable? It can't be a transition state issue because I'v tried states that should be valid as a next step. As an example the workitem is new so Approved is a valid next step.

Please if anyone has any idea what is the problem I'd be very grateful.

Example Code:

```
     WorkItem workItem = s.get(0);
     Map<String, String> fieldValueMap = settings.getFieldValues();
     String status_field_text = settings.getFieldMap().get(SettingsParser.STATUS);
     Field statusField = workItem.getFields().getField(status_field_text);
     String currentFieldValue =  fieldValueMap.get(SettingsParser.CLOSED_STATE);
     if(currentFieldValue != null)
     {

     statusField.setValue("Approved");//<=========== no matter what i add there i get exception
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("pp");
      }
```

Exception in thread "main

Error:

" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field id [10013] does not exist in this collection (wi=16,size=13)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.fields.FieldCollectionImpl.newIllegalFieldIDException(FieldCollectionImpl.java:119)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.fields.FieldCollectionImpl.getFieldInternal(FieldCollectionImpl.java:459)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.WorkItemImpl.getRuleTargetField(WorkItemImpl.java:769)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.rules.RuleEngine.preProcessFields(RuleEngine.java:224)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.rules.RuleEngine.fieldChanged(RuleEngine.java:196)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.rules.RuleEngine.fieldChanged(RuleEngine.java:167)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.fields.FieldImpl.fireRules(FieldImpl.java:795)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.fields.FieldImpl.setValue(FieldImpl.java:765)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.fields.FieldImpl.setValue(FieldImpl.java:457)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.workitem.internal.fields.FieldImpl.setValue(FieldImpl.java:389)
    at Test.main(Test.java:54)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `SettingsParser` in the TEE SDK.  I'm not sure what this class is, but it is not helpful to updating a bug.  By using it, it appears that you're trying to update the field named "10013", which does not exist.

The state field is called `System.State`, or better, you can simply use a constant, `CoreFieldReferenceNames.STATE` to refer to it.

If you look at the samples included with the SDK, you will find one (`EditWorkItemByID`) that should illustrate editing a work item for you.  Adapting that snippet and the code you've posted above, you should try something like:

```
WorkItem workItem = s.get(0);
workItem.getFields().getField(CoreFieldReferenceNames.STATE).setValue("Approved");
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment however it does provide the same error. SettingsParser is just a class i'm using to map a string to a settings string in tfs so your okay to ignore that. I looked at snippet code all that kis doing is setting the title. I have no problem creating and editing tickets. It is the changing of the state that is driving me to drink. So, I'm actually using System.State as the string as should be used. CoreFieldReferenceNames.STATE and System.State are producing that same exception. Strange thing is in the debugger you can see its finding the right field.